# Stuck using jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I've got hree html tables which I wanted to put into tabs.

All three tables can be loaded using `AJAX` but i want to show the first table and ALSO allow the first table to be ajaxable.

Lastly, I need to have the option for the user to SEARCH in the 3rd tab and those results (html result) goes into that tab.

**The problem is: When I run my current code, it's not allowing me to click the tabs (it shows some uglyish style in FireFox) and the 3rd tab is only shown.**

this is the before.

```
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<table>....data_A....</table>
<br/><br/>

<h2>Title 2</h2>
<table>....data_A....</table>
<br/><br/>

<h2>Title 3 - Search</h2>
<input id="name" type="textbox" />
<input id="search" type="submit" value="Search" />    
<br/><br/>
```

and this is my jQuery attempt code.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="JavaScriptContent" runat="server">
<link type="text/css" href="../../Content/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</SCRIPT>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li href="ajax/data_a">Title 1</li>
        <li href="ajax/data_b">Title 2</li>
        <li href="#tab-3">Search</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1">
        .... data_A table is put here ... 
        .... but will be updated via ajax when the tabs is clicked.
    </div>        
    <div id="tab-3">
        <input id="name" type="textbox" />
        <input id="search" type="submit" value="Search" />    
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

can anyone help me? what have i done wrong?

cheer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have an `a` tag inside the `li`'s. `li`'s don't have the `href` attribute.

```
<li><a href="ajax/data_a">Title 1</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax/data_b">Title 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-3">Search</a></li>
```

Just at the source here: http://stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs_3/